# New instance from a manually loaded assembly

Tags: c#

For an auto-update scenario, I'd like app to automatically pull down an updated dll from the cloud. In my VS project, I have an assembly (v1.0.0.0) referenced. I'd like to load a newer version (for example v1.1.0.0) of it at runtime, so that when I new it up:

```
var class1 = new Class1();
```

I'd like to get an **instance** of type (Class1) from assembly version v1.1.0.0. Is this even possible?

Note: I'm not looking a way to make an instance type Class1 with reflection, but newing it up.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear.

Comment: You can setup the application config to redirect version bindings.

Comment: you're going to get the class that your references indicate, if you wanted a specific version then you should load the specific assembly and load that type via `CreateInstanceAndUnwrap()`

Comment: You would have to do an assembly redirect.

Comment: @Pompair hi OP, could you have a look at this question please?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67177542/versioning-policy-with-assembly-load-and-assembly-reflectiononlyload

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [assembly redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to tell the loader to load a newer (but still compatible) assembly for your application when it's binding assemblies. This is something that you do in `app.config` or `web.config`, depending on the application type. For example (taken from the link above):

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="someAssembly" publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"
        culture="en-us" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

`oldVersion` allows for a version range, so multiple older versions can be mapped to a single new version of an assembly. Also, multiple `bindingRedirect` entries may be present.

**Edit:**

If you want to dynamically load a type from an assembly, you cannot reference the type itself (that is, you cannot have something like `Class1 obj = ...;` (`var obj = ...` is the same) because this ties the type to the one seen by the compiler. Assembly redirection would work but if you don't know the right version, you cannot use it.

Another option is to define interfaces in your main application and then have the various types in various assemblies implement these interfaces. This way you can dynamically load a type and cast it to a known interface type. For this, you can use either dependency injection (like LightInject, etc.) or you can have a config file that lists what assemblies contain a particular implementation of an interface. At the end you'd do something like:

```
IInterface obj = (IInterface) Activator.CreateInstance ( "assemblyname",
    "typename" ).Unwrap ();
```

This assumes that `assemblyname` refers to a known assembly that can be loaded and that `typename` is in that assembly and it implements `IInterface`.

Using interfaces ensures that the only hardcoded type at compile time is the interface and you can load any implementation from any assembly, as long as those implementations implement the right interface. This makes it easy to swap out various components.

Using a DI library, much of this is done for you - the various libraries deal with discovering types implementing interfaces in assemblies and then they give you a new instance when you request one.

You can also look at this answer to a similar question for some extra information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26809961/682404

Comment: This I cannot use since this would mean I'd need to know the future version number of the dll beforehand and I'd have to have access to client config file. This luxyry I don't have. The app is out in the field at users and I want to provide a patch dll via server. To the app checks for an update at app start etc. that's the easy part, but how to replace the referenced dll within the app?

Comment: @Pompair I added some details to the answer.

Comment: +1. @Pompair, you don't have to know the future version number. Just make sure that the redirect statement goes to some crazy high number like v999.999.999. Should work fine, at that point.

Comment: @xxbbcc could you have a look at this question please?

Comment: @slowjams I'm sorry, what question do you mean?

Comment: @xxbbcc sorry I forgot to post the question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67177542/versioning-policy-with-assembly-load-and-assembly-reflectiononlyload?noredirect=1#comment118746062_67177542